# Service angular vs custom class?

Tags: angular, typescript, software-design

I wonder about the approach of creating service.

I get data from server `RegistryItem[]` as JSON.

Which way to choose to create a service that handles each `RegistryItem` or create `class RegistryItem` that contains all logic like `delete()`, `edit()`?

```
class RegistryService {
   edit(registry);
   delete();
   drawRegister();
}
```

Or

```
class RegistryItem {
    edit();
    delete();
    drawRegister();

    // Other logic for drawing registry
}
```

In other words, should I wrap response items to logic class or better move logic to a specific service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practices dictate that you should separate your models and your business logic. Your **models** (types or interface) should carry out data only **without any behavior**, you make **injectable `services`** that manipulate your model:

```
export interface RegistryItem {
 id: number;
 // other related properties
}
```

And your service should contain logic related to manipulating your `RegistryItem` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RegistryItemService {
// your backend base api url
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
getAll() : Observable<RegistryItem[]> {
   return this.http.get<RegistryItem[]>(this.baseUrl+ '/registry-items')
}
update(item: RegistryItem) : Observable<RegistryItem> {...}
create(item: RegistryItem) : Observable<any> {...}
delete(id: number) : Observable<any> {...}
drawRegister() {...};
}
```

This service can be injected later and used inside your components like follow

**registry-item.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registry-item',
  templateUrl: './registry-item.component.html',
})
export class RegistryItemComponent {
  registryItems: RegistryItem[] = [];
  constructor(private service: RegistryItemService ) { 
    this.service.getAll().subscribe(res=>  {
            this.registryItems = res;
           },
         err=> console.error(err)
      );
  }

}
```

**registry-item.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>Registry items<h1/>
   <!-- 
     show your data in a list or table or whatever you like
    -->
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of registryItems"> 
      <span>{{i.id}} </span>
      <!-- show other info
       <span>{{i.name}} </span> -->
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and add `RegistryHttpService` that makes http requests and returns data to model?  I try to see all relations between classes, and should I inject  `RegistryItem` into `RegistryItemService`?

Comment: You do not and can not inject a plain model into service, why would you?, only `Services` are injectable

Comment: For exampe to prepare response data! I dont get how and where to create layer that mnakes requests and returns data. How to fill model and store?

Comment: For example I need to store all returned data `RegistryItem[]` from server

Comment: you can either expose that via a method in your service `getAll(): RegistryItem[]` and call that from your component and store them inside it. or declare a property inside your singleton service that contains that data.

Comment: Could you share an example I will accept your answer, it is unclear for me

Comment: Should I create a class model for whole response or for response items?

Comment: that depends on the response you receive from the backend, my solution assumes you receive a list of `RegistryItem`

Comment: I want to store `registryItems: RegistryItem[] = [];` inside service to be able share this data.  Also what if I need to add additioal property into `RegistryItem`? Is it good idea to modify intial daa? O nwhich step to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a singleton service.
So no matter where you inject it into the app, you always share the same service instance (there is no reason to create multiple instances of this service).
We can achieve that by either providing it in "root" or in "plaform" in the injectable decorator (see example below):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RestApiService {
  
  // Define API
  apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /*========================================
    CRUD Methods for consuming RESTful API
  =========================================*/

  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }  

  // HttpClient API get() method => Fetch employees list
  getEmployees(): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.get<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees')
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  // HttpClient API get() method => Fetch employee
  getEmployee(id): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.get<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }  

  // HttpClient API post() method => Create employee
  createEmployee(employee): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.post<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees', JSON.stringify(employee), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }  

  // HttpClient API put() method => Update employee
  updateEmployee(id, employee): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.put<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id, JSON.stringify(employee), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  // HttpClient API delete() method => Delete employee
  deleteEmployee(id){
    return this.http.delete<Employee>(this.apiURL + '/employees/' + id, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  // Error handling 
  handleError(error) {
     let errorMessage = '';
     if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
       // Get client-side error
       errorMessage = error.error.message;
     } else {
       // Get server-side error
       errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
     }
     return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

}
```

This example was not produced by me, I took it from this [guide](https://www.positronx.io/angular-7-httpclient-http-service/).
But I am pretty sure I would have implemented more or less the same exact code, so just copied it.

Just a few comments on the code:

I wouldn't define the API URL endpoint in the service, you might need to access different APIs from different environments (e.g. local/QA/prod), so I would store the endpoint as a string in the environment files (e.g `environment.[targetENV].ts`) that are created automatically by Angular CLI. Of course, if you plan to access always the same API from every ENV, you can do it exactly like in the example. Otherwise, you can assign a different API endpoint to each environment file that you have and import it then into your service to use it.
A screenshot of ENV files:

[image: example image of env files]

This is an example of how you might want to structure the env file.

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
API_URL: 'http:/blabla.com/blabla/api',
API_EMPLOYEE: 'http://test.api.com/test-api/api',
```

};

If your code might be used on one web page that runs multiple Angular applications, you might want to provide it in "platform" instead of in "root". To be 100% that only one service instance is used.

To achieve that simply change the injectable decorator from:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

to:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'platform'
})
```

Comment: You mixed business logic with http logic and model. All together. But I want deparate core business logic from http request and model that I get from requests

Comment: I am not sure about what do you mean by "model".
A model is used to instantiate a class, usually more than once. My whole answer is based on the fact that such a service/class shall be instantiated just *once*. You don't need a model for this kind of service, hence there is no mix between logic and model.
I am only providing a simple example that is easy to understand for everybody, then if you have to do complex calculations or want to split things... it's up to you. But that's out of the scope of your question.